# Writing FS with FUSE, function not implemented error when `cat>a`

Tags: c, bash, system-calls, fuse

I'm writing FS with FUSE, here are the functions I've implemented:

`create` `open` `read` `write` `release` `unlink` `mkdir` `opendir` `readdir` `releasedir` `rmdir` `getattr` `rename`

Everything works fine, except this case: when I first try `cat>a` (when a file still does not exist) it works fine: creates "a" and lets me write something in it.

But when I type again `cat>a` It tells me `-bash: a: Function not implemented`. (Similar message appears when I try to modify file with `nano a` it opens let's me write in, but after trying to save modifications the same message appears in `nano`)

What can be the cause? Which function may I me missing? Or which function may be implemented not properly?

Comment: How do you initialize the permissions bits for the newly created file.... the access bits don't affect the creation, but do in ulterior `open(2)`s.

Comment: when using `getattr` -->  `if(S_ISDIR(stbuf->st_mode)){
        stbuf->st_mode |= 0775;
    } if(S_ISREG(stbuf->st_mode)){
        stbuf->st_mode |= 0664;
    } else {
        stbuf->st_mode |= 0775;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the mount was done with the `atomic_o_trunc` option, you need to implement `truncate()` for `open()` with `O_TRUNC` (as is used when opening a file with `>` rather than `>>`) to succeed.

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it tomorrow. And will accept answer! But here is another question: In this FS I'm doing such a thing (for testing purposes): `gcc hello.c -o a.out`, It does everything, but `a.out` is not executable, it's just ordinary file? What or where may I be missing something? (BTW useful +1)

Comment: Check that your `create()` actually honors the `mode_t` argument. Would want to see a dedicated question about the creation permissions if it isn't apparent.

Comment: I think bash uses `openat`